# I need to measure the response time for a file export using Trueclient protocol in loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to measure the response time for a file export using Trueclient protocol in loadrunner.After i click on the export button the file will get downloaded. But i am not able to measure the time for the download accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull that data from the HTTP request log, which will show the download request, and, if the w3c time-taken value is included in the log, the time required to fulfill the download.

You can process the log at the end of the test for the response time data.  If you need to, you cam import a set of datapoints into analysis for representation with the rest of your data.  You might want to consider a normalized value for your download, instead of a raw response time.  I imagine that the files are of different sizes, so naturally they will have different download times.  However, if you divide download bytes with time (in seconds), then you will have a normalized measurement of bytes per second which then allows you to compare one download to the next for consistent operation.

Also, keep in mind that since you are downloading a file, writing to a local disk, for (presumably) multiple users on a host, you will face the risk of turning your local file system into a bottleneck.  You can see this same effect if you turn up logging on all users to the highest level and run your test.  The wait for lock and wait for write, plus the actual writing of data, becomes a drag anchor to the performance of your virtual user.  This is why the recommended log level is "log on error" or send the error to the output window of the controller via **lr_output_message()** or **lr_vuser_status_message()**.  Consider a control load generator of the same hardware definition as the others with only a single virtual user of this type on it.   If the control group and global group degrade together then you have an app issue.  If your control user does not degrade, but your other users do, then you have a test bed induced influence on your results.

These are all issues independent of the tool you are using for the test.